# Set initial text displayed in Combobox from code in Codename one

Tags: java, combobox, codenameone

I'm trying to set the initial a combobox displays, it should be from code. The elements in my combobox are strings.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? Perhaps how you are creating the combobox?

Comment: Yeah. Well I'm using the beforeForm "event" to initialize all my buttons and comboboxes, for the comboboxes I'm using something like findECor1(f).setSelectedItem(Integer.toString(zona1.giveGlobalStateCurtains()));

where eCor1 is my combobox. It doesn't work, however haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how did you fill the combo box to begin with?

I'm assuming the combo box isn't filled with integers. If you want to select by an offset you need to invoke `setSelectedIndex` not `setSelectedItem`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I thought maybe the setSelectedIndex only worked when you had populated your combobox with ints. Obviously I was wrong.